# ORA-01427 Single-row subquery returns more than one row when doing count(*)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running the following query that does a count and it keeps giving me the error I stated above...

```
execute immediate 
  'select count(*) from "'||rec.table_name||'" WHERE "'||rec.column_name||'" LIKE ('''||l_str||''')' 
  into l_count;
```

End result is either 0 or 1, so I don't understand why it says that.

The full query is this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON size 30000;
declare
    l_count number := 0;
    l_str varchar2(20) := '%WORD%';
begin
    for rec in (select table_name, column_name
                from user_tab_columns
                where data_type in ( 'CLOB', 'VARCHAR', 'VARCHAR2', 'TEXT' )
               ) loop
        execute immediate
            'select count(*) from "'||rec.table_name||'" WHERE "'||rec.column_name||'" LIKE ('''||l_str||''')' 
            into l_count;
        if l_count > 0 then
            dbms_output.put_line('FOUND!!! - EXECUTE THIS: SELECT * FROM '||rec.table_name||' WHERE '||rec.column_name || ' LIKE'''||l_str||''';');
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
/
quit;
```

Comment: Is l_str a sql query?

Comment: l_str is l_str varchar2(20) := '%@@PATTERN@@%';
@@PATTERN@@ is later on replaced by a script that I execute for a random work like... TEST... or WORK...

Comment: Call me crazy, but I don't even see a subquery here.

Comment: This depends a great deal on the content of `l_str`. Imagine, for example, this string: `';select 123 from dual into l_count;--` See SQL injection for an explanation.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that it's this line that's giving you the error? It looks like you're looping through a cursor - therefore please update your question to add in the code surrounding the execute immediate, since I'm wondering if it's actually an issue with the cursor you're looping through.

Comment: I've added the full query to my initial question. Error is: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
ORA-06512: at line 8
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"


Line 8 is where the loop begins, right before execute immediate

Comment: I executed it without errrors ( i tried both the whole script and the single count SELECT).

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it runs perfectly fine but depending on some tables, it gives that error.

Comment: Could it be caused when you try to do LIKE on CLOB (or TEXT) datatype?

Comment: Could be... I'm doing that because for some reason, whoever created the tables i'm going through, decided to put text in CLOB fields... Unfortunately I cannot change that and I have to scan those field types too...

Comment: Try to see if it depends from that datatypes, isolating the table (add WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE or = ).

Comment: What do you mean?  Adding a where table name in the execute immediate?

Comment: To understand the cause (in this case verify if it could depend by datatype), try to reduce the "object of observation". I thought (and I am doing some tests too) inserting more where condition in your first query (FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS)

Comment: My intention is to find the value sent in l_str in any and all tables that have a column that are type clob, varchar, varchar2, text, etc... that i define in the WHERE. What other condition could I add if this is what i'm searching for?

Comment: I wrote "to understand the cause"... It's just for test, to help you find exactly what is the cause of the problem.  Once you find the true cause, you can try to find a solution...

Comment: Rewrite this to: 1. Put the query to be executed into a string 2. Execute the query from the string 3. Add an exception handler to dump the query out when the error occurs. Then you can run the failing query separately and perhaps will be able to understand why this happens. Without access to your database there's no way for anyone here to debug your code for you. Best of luck.

Comment: Ok I found the issue. Using VARCHAR2 in the data_type causes this error... Which is even weirder because I need VC2...

Comment: That seems peculiar. Not least because Oracle substitutes VARCHAR2 for VARCHAR when we create tables.

Comment: Yeah it's very weird... I lose results if I remove varchar2, maybe its something to do with how the table is set up... Unfortunately i cant touch that... Thanks for the help guys!!